# MathJax malfunctioning (shows preview) in Firefox

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

Preview is shown alongside the render in answers I edit - not always, but most of the time. It's also sometimes the case for comments, mine and others'. I can highlight and copy the pre-renders; in HTML it's `<span class="MathJax_Preview">`.

This started since a few days ago. Reproduced at DSP.SE, Math.SE, Stats.SE, MathOverflow.SE. Not reproduced with Microsoft Edge or Chrome.

I've not tried resetting the browser, but I've not changed any browser settings (or extensions) recently, nor updated the browser. I'm using `Firefox Developer Edition 113.0b8 (64-bit)` on Windows 10.

[image]

#### Some debug info

1. When I edit others' answers and then press `F5` and confirm "Leave page", it renders properly - but when editing my own answer, I'm kicked out of edit mode. MathJax stays proper until editing any part of the answer that's MathJax, or editing enough non-MathJax.
2. [Example MathJax](https://pastebin.com/p0MKPbkK) for repro, try editing into any existing post (e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4507109/edit), without submitting of course). Not minimal, but bigger = likelier failure.
3. Comments example: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZhDi.png) expanding, [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v28m2.png)
4. I don't know what this means, just dumping it here

[image]